# Getting the Halo property of a point light in Unity

Tags: unity, lighting

I am adding point lights in my scene ( max 6 ) and I want to be able to enable its Halo property via script. However in the documentation reference, they haven't mentioned how to enable the halo property of a light source via script.

This is what I have so far.

```
GameObject lightObj = new GameObject("Light");
lightObj.AddComponent<Light>();
lightObj.light.color = Color.blue;
lightObj.transform.position = city.transform.position + new Vector3(-6.0f,0,0);
```

Point Lights have a property "Draw Halo" on the Inspector but how do I enable it via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [Halo class documentation](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/toggle-halo-from-script.41944/), lights do some magic behind the scenes to automatically create a Halo component, but hide it from the hierarchy (much like how [AudioSource.PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)() will automatically create and destroy new AudioSources while hiding them from the hierarchy). It seems the Halo component is not exposed. However, there is a workaround.

In my tests (using Unity 4.5.5) using the answers found in [this Unity forum thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/toggle-halo-from-script.41944/), I could not access the automatically created Halo via script, but if I added the Halo component to the light manually (Component -> Effects -> Halo) then I could access it via script according to [the answer given by Thundergod44](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/toggle-halo-from-script.41944/#post-714751), which I'll quote (with minor modifications) below:

```
//It's possible with C# and System.Reflection:

var haloComponent = lightObj.GetComponent("Halo");
var haloEnabledProperty = haloComponent.GetType().GetProperty("enabled");
haloEnabledProperty.SetValue(haloComponent, enable, null);
```

You'll need to replace "enable" in that last line above with a boolean value. Enabled is true, disabled is false.

Admittedly, I'm pretty inexperienced with lights/halos and reflection, so you may have better luck getting things to work with the automatically created Halo component than I did. But I can confirm that manually adding a Halo component will allow you to work around this seeming oversight by Unity to expose the Halo component.

A tangential fact that I found to be an interesting explanation as to why I couldn't figure out how to add a Halo component via script is that GetComponent("Halo").GetType() returns *Behaviour*. That's a type I'd never seen before. You'll need to know this if you wish to use strong typing when declaring variables or getting the component. e.g.:

```
Behaviour haloComponent;

void Awake() {
    haloComponent = (Behaviour)lightObj.GetComponent("Halo");
}
```